(Propensity Score) Matching for multiple outcome variables
I have multiple outcomes (dependent variables) of interest. Before estimating the effect of receiving treatment on these multiple outcomes, I want to use propensity score matching as my control and treatment groups are unbalanced across some control variables.
From my understanding, matching estimates the probability of receiving treatment based on defined covariate variables and, from this, builds the propensity score. In this process no outcome variable is included. However, running psmatch2 in Stata requires the specification of an outcome variable. As this command already estimates ATT etc this makes sense. Running pstest afterwards shows the means of the treatment and control group before and after matching. Here, no outcome variables needs to be specified. But when comparing pstest outputs for different outcome variables in the psmatch2 command, the means differ slightly, hence, my question:
Do I have to run the matching for each outcome variable individually?
At this point, I am only interested in the quality of the matching.
